# How can I get all matches of string in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I wanna get all matches of string my regex about arount specific string.

Start with `$t('` and end with `'`.

So, I use expression `/(?<=\$t\(')(.*)(?=')/gi` but it didn't work.

in this sentances I want get `aaa.bbb`, `ccc.ddd`, `eee.fff`, but it matched `aaa.bbb`, `ccc.ddd', ['name', 'age` and `eee.fff`

I wanna match end with first `'`. How can I use expression?

```
$t('aaa.bbb')
$t('ccc.ddd', ['name', 'age'])
$t('eee.fff', [
    'name',
    'age',
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for non-gready groups. (`.*?`)

`/(?<=\$t\(')(.*?)(?=')/gi`

Comment: Also TS can explicitly match not-' symbols. ``/(?<=\$t\(')[^']*/gi``